# get certain string inside string PHP

Tags: php, string

Let say I have this string:

```
$myString = "I love to [answer]PROGRAM[/answer]";
```

How can I parse this string to get the string "PROGRAM" in PHP?

Thanks,
I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Will it always be surrounded in the `[answer]`/`[/answer]` tags?

Comment: yup it surrounded....like bbcode or something...but how to retrieve those value. ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `preg_match` function to extract the stuff between `[answer]` and `[/answer]`

```
$myString = "I love to [answer]PROGRAM[/answer]";

if(preg_match('!\[answer\](.*?)\[/answer\]!',$myString,$matches)) {
   $answer = $matches[1];
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/5KJEN)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Explained this soooo much better :)

Answer (score 1):

use explode and then an array position... example:

```
$text = "my string [tag]separated[tag] by tags";
$array = explode("[tag]",$text);

echo $array[1]; // "separated"
```

The explode will split your string into arrays cut by the string "[tag]", you can change the first parameter of the function to everything you want, in this case "[answer]".

Luck ;)